# Building Code::Blocks from source isn't working

Tags: linux, gnu-make, codeblocks

For some strange reason, When I try to make Code::Blocks, it fails, saying there is an error in the source code.

This is what commands I ran:

```
export ACLOCAL_FLAGS="-I `wx-config --prefix`/share/aclocal"
./bootstrap
./configure
```

Then I ran `make`, but it throws this at me:

```
sc_wxtypes.cpp: In function ‘void ScriptBindings::Register_wxTypes()’:
sc_wxtypes.cpp:357:57: error: no matching function for call to ‘SqPlus::SQClassDef<wxFileName>::func(<unresolved overloaded function type>, const char [10])’
  357 |                 func(&wxFileName::Normalize, "Normalize").
      |                                                         ^
In file included from ../../../../src/include/scripting/bindings/sc_base_types.h:27,
                 from sc_wxtypes.cpp:18:
../../../../src/include/scripting/sqplus/sqplus.h:1759:16: note: candidate: ‘template<class Func> SqPlus::SQClassDef<TClassType>& SqPlus::SQClassDef<TClassType>::func(Func, const SQChar*) [with Func = Func; TClassType = wxFileName]’
 1759 |   SQClassDef & func(Func pfunc,const SQChar * name_) {
      |                ^~~~
../../../../src/include/scripting/sqplus/sqplus.h:1759:16: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
sc_wxtypes.cpp:357:57: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘Func’
  357 |                 func(&wxFileName::Normalize, "Normalize").
      |                                                         ^
sc_wxtypes.cpp:362:33: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
  362 |                 func<WXFN_SETCWD>(&wxFileName::SetCwd, "SetCwd").
      |                                 ^
sc_wxtypes.cpp:362:35: error: left operand of comma operator cannot resolve address of overloaded function
  362 |                 func<WXFN_SETCWD>(&wxFileName::SetCwd, "SetCwd").
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
sc_wxtypes.cpp:363:17: error: request for member ‘func’ in ‘((void)0, "SetCwd")’, which is of non-class type ‘const char [7]’
  363 |                 func(&wxFileName::SetExt, "SetExt").
      |                 ^~~~
sc_wxtypes.cpp:368:42: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
  368 |                 func<WXFN_ISFILEWRITEABLE>(&wxFileName::IsFileWritable,"IsFileWritable");
      |                                          ^
sc_wxtypes.cpp:368:44: error: left operand of comma operator cannot resolve address of overloaded function
  368 |                 func<WXFN_ISFILEWRITEABLE>(&wxFileName::IsFileWritable,"IsFileWritable");
      |                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
sc_wxtypes.cpp: At global scope:
sc_wxtypes.cpp:432:2: fatal error: opening dependency file .deps/sc_wxtypes.Tpo: Permission denied
  432 | };
      |  ^
compilation terminated.
```

Is this something to do with the way I tried to build it, or is there an actual error in the source code?

I am using Linux Debian Bullseye with an Aarch64 architecture.

Comment: i am also getting this error on archlinux x64